# getting indexes in gridview

Tags: gridview

I have a doubt here,

I have a gridview and in that gridview I wanna get the indexes of selected rows, for example

```
foreach(gridviewrow row in gridview1.rows)
{
   checkbox chkSelectedItem=(checkbox).row.findcontrol("chkSelectedItem");

   if(chkSelectedItem.checked)
   {
       int[] count=new int[row.RowIndex];
   }
}
```

when I execute this it stores only 0s as values. how can I get the selected indexes only....can anyone help me...thanks in advance

Comment: you are declaring same array variable in each loop, and also you are not setting a value to variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
List<int> i = new List<int>();
foreach(gridviewrow row in gridview1.rows)
{
   checkbox chkSelectedItem=(checkbox).row.findcontrol("chkSelectedItem");

   if(chkSelectedItem.checked)
   {
       i.Add(row.RowIndex);
   }
}
```

`i` will have collection of all selected indexes