# How can i add SI No. in a Gridview in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I am new to wpf and MVVM,in my Gridview there is different columns, different rows.
I want to numbering each row.

ie,

```
   SI No.     Name    Age

    1         abc    12
    2         edf    15
    3         fsd    25
```

How i set this SI No. in this order using wpf mvvm??But the field SI.No can not add to the database, and when a row deleted it will be in correct order...

Comment: You can make use of the `RowHeader`..

Comment: possible duplicate of [getting indexes in gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678386/getting-indexes-in-gridview)

Comment: How can binding to the gridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

First create a class like this one:

```
public class DataWithRowNumber
{
    public int Index { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Age { get; private set; }

    public DataWithRowNumber(int index, string name, int age)
    {
        Index = index;
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
    }
}
```

Here is just some example code for your viewmodel:

```
public List<DataWithRowNumber> Data
{
    get
    {
        // just to simulate some data from db
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));

        table.Rows.Add(new object[] {"abc", 12});
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] {"edf", 15});
        table.Rows.Add(new object[] {"fsd", 25});

        // code for conversion to appropriate list
        List<DataWithRowNumber> list = new List<DataWithRowNumber>();
        int index = 1;
        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            object[] items = row.ItemArray;
            list.Add(new DataWithRowNumber(index, (string)items[0], (int)items[1]));
            index++;
        }

        return list;
    }
}
```

And in your view you have something like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Index}" Header="SI No." />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Name" />
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Age}" Header="Age" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```